# The conjugacy problem of finitely generated free group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

I would like references for algorithms solving the conjugacy problem in $F_n$ (the free group on $n$ generators)?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific algorithm? "The algorithm" implies you are, but if you are looking for any good algorithm, you should rephrase as: "Is there any reference for an algorithm for the conjugacy problem of $F_n$?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok

Comment: @ThomasAndrews By the way, do you have any idea?

Comment: @6666: Thomas was just being a bit picky about your use of English: are you happy with my edit? I would look in Magnus, Karass and Solitar in the first instance (but unfortunately, my copy is in storage just now so I can't check).

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you very much!, your edit is very good.

Comment: Its very easy. You just cyclically reduce both words and then check if one is a cyclic conjugate of the other. It's in Chapter 1 of Lyndon and Schupp.

Comment: @DerekHolt  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two words are conjugate if they have the same cyclic reduction. So, arrange your word in a circle, and start cancelling.