# $S_{\infty}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{n}$ for $n \geq 2$ are ICC groups.

Tags: symmetric-groups, free-groups, von-neumann-algebras, geometric-group-theory

I thought this was a cool question that I have not seen on the site and thought I would share.

Recall that the infinite symmetric group can be described in the following way: $S_{\infty}=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{S_n}$. Moreover, $\sigma \in S_{\infty}$ if then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$ $\sigma(n)=n$.  Prove that $S_{\infty}$ has ICC property.

Also, prove that for $n \geq 2$, $\mathbb{F}_{n}$ is an ICC group.

Comment: What does this have to do with von Neumann algebras?

Comment: The fact that $\mathbb{F}_n$ has infinitely many conjugacy classes is implicit in other math.stackexchange questions about about the conjugacy problem, for instance this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672257/the-conjugacy-problem-of-finitely-generated-free-group?rq=1

Comment: Nothing per de, but I do not know of any other fields that really care about ICC property.

Comment: The question is not about the number of conjugacy classes, rather the cardinality of every conjugacy class, which I have not seen on MSE.

Comment: @anomaly: ICC is an essential property in the construction of von Neumann algebras, because it guarantees that the von Neumann algebra generated by the left regular representation of the group is a factor (trivial centre).

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Ah, thanks. (That wasn't a rhetorical question; I know nothing at all about von Neumann algebras.)

Comment: You are welcome :) Those two groups are important because their reduced von Neumann algebras $L(\mathbb S_\infty)$ and $L(\mathbb F_2)$ were considered by Murray-von Neumann in the 1930s, and were the first example of non-isomorphic II$_1$-factors. It took some 20 years to find a third example, and 10 more years (late 60s) to show that there are uncountably many. To this day, it is not known if $L(\mathbb F_2)$ and $L(\mathbb F_3)$ are isomorphic or not.

Comment: @Martin, to be a little pedantic; the ICC property is important in the group VNA construction as being ICC for instance doesn't guarantee the crossed product construction will be a II_1 factor but a p.m.p free erogodic transitive action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $S_{\infty}$ we will prove this in the following way: let $e \neq \sigma \in S_n \subset S_{\infty}$ such that $\sigma(i) \neq i$. For $j > n$ let $s_j$ be a permutation swapping i and j. We will prove that $|\{s_j \sigma s_j^{-1}: j > n \}|=\infty$. Since $\{s_j \sigma s_j^{-1}: j > n \} \subset \{g \sigma g^{-1} : g \in S_{\infty}\}$.

Say $\sigma(i)=k$ where $k \leq n$. Then we have that $\sigma s_j^{-1}(i)=k$ and $\sigma s_j^{-1}(j)=i$ and $\forall N > n$ $\sigma s_j^{-1}(N)=N$. Then consider $s_j \sigma s_j^{-1}(i)=i$ and $s_j \sigma s_j^{-1}(j)=k$. In other words as we let j vary for all $j > n$ we end up with distinct permutations in the conjugacy class sending j to k. Hence, we conclude that $|\{s_j \sigma s_j^{-1} : j > n\}|=\infty$ and thus $S_{\infty}$ is ICC.

Recall that $\mathbb{F}_2 = \langle a,b : \text{ a and b have no relations.} \rangle$. We have 4 options on the how reduced words end in the group; namely with $a^{k},b^{k},a^{-k}$, and $b^{-k}$ where $k \geq 1$. For example say that $w(a,b)$ ends with $a^{k}$ then it is not hard to see that conjugating by $g=b^{n}a^{k}$ for $n \geq 1$ gives distinct reduced words ending in $b^{-n}$. If our reduced words are of the form $w(a,b)=a^{k},b^{k},a^{-k},b^{-k}$ the same trick will work. Thus, we conclude $\mathbb{F}_2$ is ICC. This approach can be generalized for $\mathbb{F}_n$ where $n \geq 2$ and noting that we have 2n options for how a word can end in $\mathbb{F}_n$. Thus, we conclude that in general, $\mathbb{F}_n$ is ICC.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, note that the fixed point set $\mathbb{N}^g = \{n\in \mathbb{N}:\, gn = n\}$ has $\mathbb{N}^{g^h} = h^{-1}(\mathbb{N}^g)$ for $g, h\in S_\infty$.

For the second, fix $g\not =1$ in $F_n$ with $n \geq 2$, and choose $h\in F_n$ with $h\notin\langle{g}\rangle$ and $g\not\in \langle{h}\rangle$. (To prove that such an $h$ exists, use word-length to show that the latter condition holds for only finitely many $h$.) If the set $\{g^{h^n}:\,n \geq 0\}$ is finite, then $g^{h^n} = g$ for some $n$; that is, $[h^n, g] = 1$. Hence $\langle{h^n, g}\rangle$ is abelian, contradicting the fact that any subgroup of a free group is itself free.

Comment: Why the downvote?